# Create a div with a line through the middle of a circle with text in the centre

Tags: css, responsive-design

[image]

Is it possible to create a div with a line through the middle of a circle with text in the centre like above? It needs to be responsive so it will scale with the page. here is my code so far. I need a way to draw the line behind the circle now

http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/87/

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="round-button">
        <div class="round-button-circle"><span class="round-button">G</span>

        </div>
    </div>
<div>

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
}
.round-button {
    width:25%;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button span {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: with less markup and margins, would this be what you look for : http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/89/ ?

Comment: It looks OK but doesn't quite behave as I need it. The container needs to frame the circle, so that the circle sits in the middle of the container. If the container frame resizes, so should the circle and line

Comment: It needs maybe some tunning, http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/92/  else draw the line as a background http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/93/

Comment: Close, the circles resize when the width is altered, but not when the height is altered

Comment: of course, vertical padding takes width as reference. but you have to make a choice: choose width or height as reference. If you want both, CSS is unable to mix them, even using vw and vh units. You need to set these via javascript

Comment: Thanks. Your solution has worked. I'll start another Q to see if anyone can solve the circle resizing to both width and height.

Comment: you can play with max-height/width http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/95/ but uncertain result