# Circles that respond to width AND height

Tags: html, css

Ok, here is a common css markup for responsive circles.

http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/355/

```
<div class="circle"></div>
.circle {
    width: 25%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

The trouble is that they resize OK when the width is adjusted, but not height. Is there a way to do it so that both the width and height will resize the circle?

Comment: Yes, with javascript..

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WTWrB/356/

Comment: Thanks but it only scales down, and not up when the window is made larger

Comment: I can't use px for this as the size of the circle needs to be a percantage of it's parent

Comment: That's because I added an "if" statement to the script that checks for the screen size: "if (height <= width / 100 * 25)". I don't know what the requirements are for your project, so you can't expect me to do your job. Try modifying the code and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If remove the `padding-bottom: 25%;` and give height and width in pixel then we able to resize the div by height and width here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/t2mXR/)

Comment: Have you checked the above link?

Comment: Yes it didn't resize when I dragged the handles. I just got scrollbars

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately percentages in CSS typically refer to only the width of the viewport, which is why in the above 25% height is equal to 25% width.

You could explore some of the new [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units), which can respond to the viewport height instead; media queries can also alter elements based on the viewport height, but both of these will be fairly choppy and won't resize as smoothly as using percentages.

**Edit:**

Might need some tweaking, and doesn't have the strongest browser support, but this CSS will create circles that resize both by width and height whilst maintaining aspect ratio.

```
.circle {
    width: 25vmin;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 25vmin;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #4679BD;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if margin could be used as they effect height and width proportionally...

Comment: That would very much depend how you're using the circle, I guess.

Comment: The problem with your code, is that 25vmin is 25% of the viewport, whereas before it was 25% of the div it was contained in. Can vmin be made to be 25% of its container?

Comment: Unfortunately not. vw/vh/vmin/vmax are all tied to the viewport dimensions. You may have to go for one of the javascript solutions instead.

Answer (score 0):

as commented on other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444666/create-a-div-with-a-line-through-the-middle-of-a-circle-with-text-in-the-centre), you may try max-height and max-width using vh units:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jyjjx/95/ (from your initial fiddle)

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px; /* show yourself */
    text-align:center;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 48%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 48%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 52%,
        rgba(0,0,0,0) 52%
        );

}
.round-button {
    width:25%;
    margin:auto;
    max-height:25vh;
    max-width:25vh;
}
.round-button-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:10px solid #cfdcec;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
.round-button span {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    line-height:1em;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    text-align:center;
    color:#e2eaf3;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="round-button">
        <div class="round-button-circle"><span class="round-button">G</span>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the middle line doesn't display for me in firefox 15